# Add new column to dataframe in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Thanks to inputs found in StackOverflow, I figured out how to add a column to an existing data frame based on conditions.

When I run this code chunk

```
testmain %>% 
  mutate(wealth = case_when(.$savings_1 == "0" & .$savings_5 == "0" ~ "No savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "1" & .$savings_5 == "0" ~ "1,000 Sh savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "1" & .$savings_5 == "1" ~ "5,000 Sh savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "0" & .$savings_5 == "1" ~ "Special case"))
```

the 'result' is shown in a preview window (I am writing a Markdown file in R). This result contains my newly added variable `wealth`:
[image: See last column]

When I subsequently run the code `View(testmain)` to look at the dataframe, the new variable isn't there. Can anyone give me a hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I do not think you need the .$

Comment: Hi @Annet ! I did it with and without the .$ (always according to other inputs I found in other threads, but it doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the result to something.

For example,

```
testmain2 <- testmain %>%
  mutate(wealth = case_when(.$savings_1 == "0" & .$savings_5 == "0" ~ "No savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "1" & .$savings_5 == "0" ~ "1,000 Sh savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "1" & .$savings_5 == "1" ~ "5,000 Sh savings",
                            .$savings_1 == "0" & .$savings_5 == "1" ~ "Special case"))
```

Then `View(testmain2)` should show the added column.

Side note: It's recommended to have a default value in `case_when`. You can do this by adding

```
case_when(
  x == y   ~ z,
  TRUE     ~ somedefaultvalue
)
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much :)